# mcopy says "Cannot initialize '::'" for no aparent reason

Tags: makefile, kernel, x86-16, bootloader

I have this makefile:

```
ASM = nasm

.PHONY: floppyimage kernel bootloader everything

goldos: everything
    qemu-system-i386 -fda build/goldos.img

norun: everything

everything: floppyimage kernel bootloader build

floppyimage: build/goldos.img

build/goldos.img: build bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=build/goldos.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "GOLDOS" build/goldos.img
    dd if=build/bootloader.bin of=build/goldos.img conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i build/goldos.img build/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"

bootloader: build/bootloader.bin

build/bootloader.bin: build bootloader/bootloader.asm
    $(ASM) bootloader/bootloader.asm -fbin -obuild/bootloader.bin

kernel: build/kernel.bin

build/kernel.bin: build kernel/kernel.asm
    $(ASM) kernel/kernel.asm -fbin -obuild/kernel.bin

clean:
    rm -r build

build:
    mkdir -p build
```

For some stupid reason, it started saying:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=build/goldos.img bs=512 count=2880
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes (1.5 MB, 1.4 MiB) copied, 0.00605087 s, 244 MB/s
mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "GOLDOS" build/goldos.img
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
dd if=build/bootloader.bin of=build/goldos.img conv=notrunc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 5.852e-05 s, 8.7 MB/s
mcopy -i build/goldos.img build/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
init :: non DOS media (here, the parentesis are not part of the output)
Cannot initialize '::'
::kernel.bin: Success
make: *** [makefile:18: build/goldos.img] Error 1
```

[bootloader.asm](https://github.com/GoldenStarGamer/os/blob/e9028b48e76ec3374585db3c75af9e5c77fb67da/bootloader/bootloader.asm) (on github due to over 300 lines)
i cannot run this anymore, couldn't find any info online, kernel.asm has nothing,
mcopy started acting out when I added something to that file, but i removed it.
Already tried deleting the output files, but same error.

Comment: Show bootloader.asm source.

Comment: Replace `jmp setup` by `jmp strict short setup` followed by `nop`

Comment: @ecm why, and how does that change anything, also can't add any more operations, it's at the absolute limit.

Comment: Because there are 3 bytes that are needed before the data in the BPB. Your current jump is 2 bytes long, the `nop` is a 3rd byte to ensure the BPB is in the right place. Adding the `nop` shouldn't change the size of your bootloader.

Comment: @MichaelPetch nice, but the size limit wont let me

Comment: The BPB contents must start at offset 11, and the OEM ID at offset 3. Otherwise the superblock structure doesn't match what everyone else expects. If you have no space for this single added byte you will have to re-order or optimise something. For instance, replace `mov ax, 0` by `xor ax, ax`. And `mov si, ferror_kernel_jump_failed` is never reached so you can just drop this part.

Comment: You have a size limit of 512. Adding the `NOP` will still fit within the 512 bytes of the bootloader you have in Github.

Comment: and now «, i added stuff in the kernel, but it isn't doing nothing

Comment: @GoldenStar Make a new question if you want to talk about a different problem.

Comment: When you do `int 13h` in `disk_read` you do a `pusha` to save all the registers before `int 13h` and if there is no disk error you don't do a corresponding `popa`. Your `popa` should be done right after `int 13h` not further down before the `call disk_reset`. As a result if the disk read was successful the stack is unbalanced when the `ret` is done and it goes off into memory executing memory you didn't intend.

Comment: @ecm i was question banned :(

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074284/bootloader-doesnt-seem-to-be-loading-the-kernel-but-doesnt-send-any-errors

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `jmp start` to `jmp strict short start` and added `nop` after that.
the BIOS expects 3 bytes before the header, and those operations are 3 bytes.
I was able to get more space by adding a call to `talk` inside the `fatal_reboot`, label, since every reference ran talk before `fatal_reboot`.
Thanks @ecm.